# Default NULL parameter Rcpp

Tags: r, parameters, null, rcpp

I am trying to define a function with a default `NULL` parameter in `Rcpp`. Following is an example:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test(int a, IntegerVector kfolds = R_NilValue)
{
  if (Rf_isNull(kfolds))
  {
    cout << "NULL" << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "NOT NULL" << endl;
  }

  return a;
}
```

But when I run the code:

```
test(1)
```

I get the following error:

> Error: not compatible with requested type

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Don't use `cout`, use `Rcpp::Rcout`.

Comment: @Roland why? what are the differences?

Comment: AFAIK, `cout` will only work if you run R from a terminal. There might be other problems, but I don't know. I follow the advice of my betters (such as Dirk) in these regards.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are in luck. We needed this in [mvabund](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=mvabund) and [Rblpapi](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=Rblpapi), and have it since the last (two) Rcpp releases.

So try this:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test(int a, Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::IntegerVector> kfolds = R_NilValue) {

  if (kfolds.isNotNull()) {
     // ... your code here but note inverted test ...
```

A nice complete example is [here in Rblpapi](https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi/blob/master/src/getBars.cpp#L185-L187).
You can also set a default value as you did (subject to the usual rules in C++ of all options to the right of this one also having defaults).

*Edit:* For completeness sake, here is a full example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int testfun(Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::IntegerVector> kfolds = R_NilValue) {

  if (kfolds.isNotNull()) {
    Rcpp::IntegerVector x(kfolds);
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Not NULL\n";
    Rcpp::Rcout << x << std::endl;
  } else {
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Is NULL\n";
  }
  return(42);
}

/*** R
testfun(NULL)
testfun(c(1L, 3L, 5L))
*/
```

which generates this output:

R> sourceCpp("/tmp/nick.cpp")

```
R> testfun(NULL)
Is NULL
[1] 42

R> testfun(c(1L, 3L, 5L))
Not NULL
1 3 5
[1] 42
R>
```